# Count all from another table

Tags: mysql

I have one table like this:

a. tbl_cdr 
[image: tbl_cdr]

b. tbl_wo_notification_contacts
[image: tbl_wo_notification_contacts]

What I want was count all from tbl_wo_notification_contacts and tbl_cdr. Here is my query.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(n.last_attempt,1,10) AS DATE, 
SUM(IF(n.STATUS=1, 1,0)) AS 'Success', 
SUM(IF(n.STATUS=2, 1,0)) AS 'Failed', 
COUNT(*) AS 'TotalCalls'
FROM tbl_wo_notification_contacts n
WHERE n.last_attempt >= '2019-05-01' AND n.last_attempt <= '2019-07-01'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(n.last_attempt,1,10);
```

The problem is I want to add new column called 'Total Duration' where it counts all from tbl_cdr based on the query condition.

Comment: Instead of `SUBSTRING(n.last_attempt, 1, 10)`, use `DATE(n.last_attempt)`.

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Comment: What are you counting in `tbl_cdr`? What is the query condition?

Comment: Are you sure your `IF()` condition is correct? The values of `status` in the table are `0` and `1`, not `1` and `2`.

Comment: i will count all from tbl_cdr based on date from tbl_wo_notification_contacts

Comment: yes the IF is correct. I have 0 to 4 status.

Comment: I still don't understand. The date is in the other table, how can you count from `tbl_cdr` based on that? How are rows in `tbl_cdr` related to rows in `tbl_wo_notification_contacts`?

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like a foreign key between the two tables.

Comment: Can you show what the desired result should look like?

Comment: Is ContactsID the foreign key?

Comment: Yes the ContactsID is from foreign key for tbl_wo_notification_contacts

Answer (score 0):

Group `tbl_cdr` by `ContactsID` to get the counts.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(n.last_attempt,1,10) AS DATE, 
        SUM(IF(n.STATUS=1, 1,0)) AS 'Success', 
        SUM(IF(n.STATUS=2, 1,0)) AS 'Failed', 
        COUNT(*) AS 'TotalCalls',
        IFNULL(c.TotalDuration, 0) AS TotalDuration
FROM tbl_wo_notification_contacts n
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ContactID, COUNT(*) AS TotalDuration
    FROM tbl_cdr
    GROUP BY ContactID) AS c ON c.ContactID = n.id
WHERE n.last_attempt >= '2019-05-01' AND n.last_attempt <= '2019-07-01'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(n.last_attempt,1,10);
```